# Migrating away from core data

Tags: swift, core-data

Our team is in the process of moving from core data to GRDB.  One issue is the transition from the 2 databases and keeping them in sync as we test.

One idea would be to just keep using the sqlite DB that core data has created directly, or to make a copy and if we revert, copy it back in place with the updated records.

Anyone have any experience with this concept, looking for any issues we might encounter.

Comment: This is not a good Q for SO. But before it will be closed: you are basically performing "refactoring". This requires you have a nice architecture separated into layers and components, each component having unit tests. Since a relational DB _is not_ a CoreData container and has different semantics and features, you need a sufficient abstraction above your "data provider" ensuring your "Scenes" still work. I can imagine, this is a challenge, unless you are using only basic features of CoreData.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I guess the essence of my question is can we mess with core data's backing tables if we are not using them in the application at the same time?

Comment: "can we mess with core data's backing tables if we are not using them in the application at the same time" I'm far from being a Core Data expert, but doing this does not seem to be reliable. Core Data uses SHM (shared memory file) and WAL (write-ahead logging) files in addition to the sqlite file itself, and it also does not necessarily use tables, rows, and keys, the way we would expect. Modifying the Core Data backing store without using Core Data itself seems dangerous (data loss, data corruption).

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this right now. I think that if you prepare good persistence layer abstraction like protocols and their implementations for different databases, where protocol do not have dependency to the specific database library classes and data types, then migration should be fine and quite easy. After that, once you have Core Data implementation, you can write another implementation with GRDB and switch to it in your application. It's strategy software design pattern.